# Codeigniter Calendar Not Displaying Some Record

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Ok so i'm trying to create a calendar using codeigniter and the feeds are attendance records, i tried styling using bootstrap to make it look better.
The previous records are being displayed, but some records especially recent dates are not showing. I tried displaying the query result and there's the record but the date in the calendar is empty

here's the calendar model

```
class Calendar_model extends CI_Model {

var $conf;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->conf = array(
        'start_day' => 'monday',
        'show_next_prev' => true,
        'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'employee/employee_attendance'
        );

    $this->conf['template'] = '
    {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar table">{/table_open}

    {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

    {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-lg-7" title="Previous Month"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button></span></a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
    {heading_title_cell}<th class="text-center"colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
    {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-5" title="Previous Month"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button></span></a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

    {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

    {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
    {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
    {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

    {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
    {cal_cell_start}<td class="day">{/cal_cell_start}

    {cal_cell_content}
    <div class="day_num present">{day}</div>
    <div class="content present" id="present"> 
    <div class="text-center">
    <span class="label label-default" style="display:block; width:80%;">{content}
    </div>
    </div>
    {/cal_cell_content}
    {cal_cell_content_today}
    <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
    <div class="content">{content}</div>
    {/cal_cell_content_today}

    {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content}
    {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

    {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

    {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
    {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

    {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
    ';

}

function get_calendar_data($year, $month, $username) {
    $this->db->like('date', "$year-$month-", 'after');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('attendance',array('username'=>$username, 'status'=> 'present'));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $data[substr($row->date,8,2)] = $row->login_time.'</span><span class="label label-danger" style="display: block; width: 80%;">'.$row->logout_time.'</span><span class="label label-warning" style="display:block; width:80%;">'.$row->accumulated_time.'mins </span>';
        }
        return $data;

    }
}

function generate ($year, $month) {
    $this->load->library('calendar', $this->conf);
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year, $month, $username);
    return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $cal_data);

}
}
```

Here's the screeshots

Data from previous dates :http://s2.postimg.org/tray4d3rd/Capture.png

Recent dates are not: http://s1.postimg.org/tr09y389b/image.png

They're all dates, so i'm not sure why some data isn't there
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you tag this as laravel if it is for codeigniter?

Comment: Is the final HTML is correctly formatted ? I had some issues with CI templates and bootstrap in the past.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange coz i think most of the users of laravel are also familiar with codeigniter, well i'm sorry about that